# Calculated field that shows the result of a query

Tags: ms-access-2013

In MS Access (2013 if it matters), is it possible to have a calculate field in a table that displays the result of a query on another table?

For example, let's say my tables are (stars indicate primary key) -

**Table `Customers`**

```
*Customer ID | First name | Last name
------------------------------------
1            | John       | Doe
2            | Joe        | Smith
```

**Table `Purchases`**

```
*Purchase ID |Customer ID | Product    | Last name | Notes
----------------------------------------------------------
25           |1           | Chair      | Doe       | 
45           |1           | Table      | Doe       |
46           |2           | Table      | Smith     |
```

Every time a customer buys something, I add a a new row to `Purchases`. However, when I type in their `Customer ID`, I would like `Last name` to be filled in automatically.

Comment: That's quite a strange modelling of the data - is there a reason to persist Last name in the Purchases table?  Do you want it for future reference on a receipt or something?  If not, why not just JOIN the two tables on CustomerID and get it from the Customers table for and drop the column from Purchases?

Comment: @VBlades I use the database to keep track of my inventory. When I look at the table analogous to `Purchases` in my database, I want to see the column corresponding to `Last name` as I scroll by, without having to switch back and forth between the two tables (sometimes I think, "*what was the name of the guy who bought this again?*"). I realize this duplicates data and isn't a very "proper" way to do it. I suppose you will suggest me to make a report, but I cannot easily edit the report in place and immediately see the results.

Comment: Ok, I guess you do your editing straight in datasheet view?  There are a couple ways to do it, then.  Here's an easy way that worked for me in Access 2007.  Pop this code into a query: SELECT Purchases.*, Customers.[Last Name]
FROM Customers INNER JOIN Purchases ON Customers.[Customer ID] = Purchases.[Customer ID]
ORDER BY Purchases.[Purchase ID];
(Hope I got all the field names right.) Save it off.  Open it up.  In my version, the customer last name will appear once you enter the Customer ID.  Let me know.  (May lose juice now, but will check later if so.)

Comment: @VBlades Won't this make a query, instead of populating the fields of an existing table?

Comment: Superbest you are correct this will make a query. What @VBlades is suggesting is that you use this query to check the table analagous to Purchases rather than using the table itself. I don't think there is any simple way to do what you are trying to do. If you really need to insert a record from one table into another you need to create a form and write some VBA for the After Insert event or change to SQL server and use a trigger

Comment: @Superbest: Yes, that is correct.  As William Smith wrote, you should use this query to update your Purchases table.  When you enter data into the query, it will be inserted into the underlying table (Purchases).  The query construction is basically telling to look up the Last Name in Customer based on the Customer ID.  It's important to note that in doing it this way, the Last Name will not get inserted into your Purchases table.  If you are using Access 2013, there is probably a way to do it with a table trigger as well, but I haven't got a version to play around with.